# Icon Preview for internal images not working

Tags: python, interface

Here is an example file for internal images that should be displayed with the `template_icon_view` or just as enum property.
This works if the files are saved externally. At least for if used with `layout.prop()` but not with `layout.template_icon_view()`

Is there a way to get this internal images displayed by the `template_icon_view`? I get the image ID and the enum properties are generated correctly but the icon preview doesn't work.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1250100/Blender/template_icon_view.blend

Comment: This seems more like a bug report than a question.